# Restarting Rails for terminal session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I was doing the [Ruby on Rails tutorial by Martl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and closed my terminal on my Mac. I had reached Chapter 10 without a problem. When I opened another terminal nothing is working. When I run bundle install I get the following error message:

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [rake-0.8.7, rake-0.8.7] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:18

How do I get my terminal back to where it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your RVM environment is not being loaded when you restart your terminal.  The Ruby On Rails tutorial glosses over RVM installation rather quickly and thats why this step often gets missed.

Check out the RVM installation guide [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) in particular Section 2 which describes how to ensure the RVM commands go into your .bash_profile.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I did the following: $>bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm) ---- $>echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile --- $>source .bash_profile --- $>type rvm | head -1 --- which returns is a function --- when I try $>rails server I get the following error: /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [rake-0.9.2, rake-0.8.7, rake-0.8.7] (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec' ...

Comment: ok, so you need to run the bundle command from within your project (this will install the required gems).